# DateTime.TryParse fails for one user

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to parse dates in my program, but it fails on the machine of one user (in denmark). It works for his colleagues who all has the same settings as far as I can tell.

The code looks as follows:

```
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParse(InputBox.Text, out result))
    YyyymmddField.Text = result.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
else
    YyyymmddField.Text = "(invalid)";
```

`CurrentCulture` is `da-DK` and his configured format is: `yyyy.MM.dd`. The date string I want to parse is `2015.07.14`.
This works on our machines here (in sweden) regardless of current culture. It also works for his colleagues, but not for him.

We have hundreds of users worldwide and as far as we know, his is the only computer that fails.

Could something other than the current `CultureInfo` affect how `TryParse` operates?

Comment: I suggest you change you data example to something more clear where the month is, like `2015.12.01`

Answer (score 7):

> This works on our machines here (in sweden) **regardless of current
>   culture**

No. There is no such a thing. If you use `DateTime.TryParse` without any `IFormatProvider`, it will use the `CurrentCulture` settings of the current machine.

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> The string s is parsed using formatting information in the current
>   `DateTimeFormatInfo` object, which is supplied implicitly by the **current**
>   thread culture.

I'm using .NET Framework 4.5 and there are only 7 culture inside of `AllCultures` that doesn't have this as standard date and time format. If you won't/can't tell us what is your other colleague's `CurrentCulture`, I would assume he will use one of these from my perspective.

```
ar
bn
ml
ar-SA
bn-IN
ml-IN
bn-BD
```

Instead of that confusion, you can use [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is your string has a stable format like `yyyy.MM.dd` instead of hoping his `CurrentCulture` settings will parse it or not.

Comment: However, `2015.07.01` works also in `en-US` or `de-DE`. Actually i haven't found a culture where it doesn't work with `DateTime.TryParse(InputBox.Text, out result)` and i have tested all 209 installed.

Comment: Yes, what I meant was that it does not matter if I change my format in the Control Panel, the result is the same.

Comment: @TimSchmelter My bad. Fixed that part. BTW, I had 7 culture that _can't_ parse it.

Comment: Well the string I get is actually from another program and I assumed that that program formats the date with the selected culture of the user. Which should mean that I could use the same to parse it, and indeed it does work for others with the same configured culture, but not for him. So I wondered not how to do it, but if anything other than the culture could affect this.
The code shown in my example is from a small test-program I wrote to test formats on his machine.

Answer (score 1):

use **CultureInfo.InvariantCulture**

```
DateTime result;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(InputBox.Text, out result))
        YyyymmddField.Text = result.ToString("yyyyMMdd",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    else
        YyyymmddField.Text = "(invalid)";
```

Comment: I think you want `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as a parameter to the `TryParse()` rather than the `ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, it can be a good idea to have reusable methods (such as extension methods) for parsing DateTimes and numerics, which use the invariant culture.